# My wordpress gallery won't open in a lightbox

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox

At http://www.chockdee.nl/fotos-thaise-massagesalon-vlaardingen/ i am trying to open the photos in a lightbox, but that's not working. I have tried different plugins to make it happen, but all of them won't do it (Nextgen, WP Lightbox Gallery and more). I'm guessing it's  javascript conflict but I can't figure out where the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Try pretty photo media plugin...there is setting in plugin you can manually turn off or load at bottom plugin's java script...https://wordpress.org/plugins/prettyphoto-media/

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately..

Comment: can you check console whether which js is conflicting ? and list down how many plugin you are using ?

Comment: - Anti-Malware and Brute-Force Security by ELI

    - Call Now Button

    - Contact Form 7

    - DesignThemes Core Features Plugin

    - Get The Image

    - LayerSlider WP

    - Like This
 
    - Limit Login Attempts

    - NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati

    - prettyPhoto Media

    - Responsive Styled Google Maps

    - Revolution Slider

    - Simplest Gallery

    - Wordfence Security

    - WordPress SEO

    - WP Canvas - Gallery

    - WP Customer Reviews

    - WP Google Maps

Comment: fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555  This is the only error i get but it seems to be Facebook likebox

Comment: are all those plugin you are using in website? if not delete unnecessary plugin to avoid conflict ion.

Answer (score 0):

All solved by using the Foobox image lightbox plugin. Workaround that works.